# Perceptron Sigmoid

Tags: c++, neural-network, openframeworks, perceptron

Hello I am trying to create a program that will calculate weights from the perceptron algorithm. I have it all working right now but with the very basics, it is a step function and it is single-layered. Before I move on to muilti-layer I am trying to make it optimal and sigmoid.

So those are my question, I have a general idea of the sigmoid but I can't find any information on how to make the line optimal, so it is equal distance from the data points. Anyone has any idea?

```
net = 0;
for(i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    net = net + (x[i] * w[i]);      //Calculates weighted sum
}

if(net >= threshold) output =  1;     //Finds the output based on the net
if(net <  threshold) output = -1;
```

This is my current code to find the "y" variable, I called it output here, and it is finding it using a simple step function, threshold = 0. How can I convert this to a sigmoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following may work:

```
output = 1 / (1 + exp(-net));
```

You may also love `tanh(net)` or `1 / (1 + abs(net))` functions, which are much faster according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15703984/1102535).

Comment: I think you meant "output = net / (1 + exp(-net));", but yeah I think that works, I guess the 2 if's statements are what makes it the step function, didn't know what to do with them, but now I get it. Is there any way to round the output value to be no more than 3-5 digits? Not trying to print it, just store it.

Comment: @maty The original sigmoid function is exact as I wrote, but you can also use `1 / (1 + exp(-beta * net))`, where beta is slope parameter. Sigmoid will give you output values from 0 to 1, `tanh` will give from -1 to 1. You can scale them also, i.e. `0.5 * tanh(net) + 0.5` if you need output in (0, 1) interval from `tanh`.