# How to find inverse of fast sigmoid function using sympy?

Tags: python, linear-algebra, sympy

I would like to solve the following equation (inspired by: [Fast sigmoid algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10733861)) for the variable x:

`0 = lower + (upper - lower) * (0.5 + 0.5 * x / (1 + abs(x))) - y`

If I use for this sympy, I get an error:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
x = Symbol('x', real=True)
y = Symbol('y', real=True)
lower = Symbol('lower', real=True)
upper = Symbol('upper', real=True)

solve(lower + (upper - lower) * (0.5 + 0.5 * x / (1 + abs(x))) -y, x)
```

error:

```
  File "/home/user/venv/numba/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/function.py", line 3082, in nfloat
    return type(expr)([nfloat(a, n, exponent) for a in expr])
  File "/home/user/venv/numba/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/function.py", line 3082, in <listcomp>
    return type(expr)([nfloat(a, n, exponent) for a in expr])
  File "/home/user/venv/numba/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sympy/core/function.py", line 3082, in nfloat
    return type(expr)([nfloat(a, n, exponent) for a in expr])
TypeError: __new__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cond'
```

**How could I solve this equation with sympy?**

(**or if somebody is able to solve the equation for `x` manually: how would the inversion of the function look like anyhow?**)

Comment: You need actual values for 'lower' and 'upper'. Exclude the 'y' parameter because default solving equates to zero. You can also visually check whether the function ever equates to zero in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in SymPy version 1.4. On master I don't get the exception and instead I get:

```
In [2]: solve(lower + (upper - lower) * (0.5 + 0.5 * x / (1 + abs(x))) -y, x)                                                                                                     
Out[2]: 
⎡⎧0.5⋅lower + 0.5⋅upper - y      0.5⋅(lower + upper - 2.0⋅y)      ⎧-0.5⋅lower - 0.5⋅upper + y      0.5⋅(-lower - upper + 2.0⋅y)    ⎤
⎢⎪─────────────────────────  for ─────────────────────────── < 0  ⎪──────────────────────────  for ──────────────────────────── ≥ 0⎥
⎢⎨        lower - y                       lower - y             , ⎨        upper - y                        upper - y              ⎥
⎢⎪                                                                ⎪                                                                ⎥
⎣⎩           nan                          otherwise               ⎩           nan                           otherwise              ⎦
```

This returns two piecewise solutions corresponding to the case of negative and positive x (I think).

I'm not happy with the result above though. I think the proper result should be something like this:

```
In [46]: eqn = lower + (upper - lower) * (0.5 + 0.5 * x / (1 + abs(x))) - y                                                                                                       

In [47]: eqn = piecewise_fold(eqn.rewrite(Piecewise))                                                                                                                             

In [48]: eqn                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[48]: 
⎧                             ⎛0.5⋅x      ⎞           
⎪lower - y + (-lower + upper)⋅⎜───── + 0.5⎟  for x ≥ 0
⎪                             ⎝x + 1      ⎠           
⎨                                                     
⎪                             ⎛0.5⋅x      ⎞           
⎪lower - y + (-lower + upper)⋅⎜───── + 0.5⎟  otherwise
⎩                             ⎝1 - x      ⎠           

In [49]: sx1, = solve(eqn.args[0][0], x)                                                                                                                                          

In [50]: sx2, = solve(eqn.args[1][0], x)                                                                                                                                          

In [51]: cx1 = eqn.args[0][1].subs(x, sx1)                                                                                                                                        

In [52]: sol = Piecewise((sx1, cx1), (sx2, True))                                                                                                                                 

In [53]: sol                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[53]: 
⎧-0.5⋅lower - 0.5⋅upper + y      -0.5⋅lower - 0.5⋅upper + y    
⎪──────────────────────────  for ────────────────────────── ≥ 0
⎪        upper - y                       upper - y             
⎨                                                              
⎪0.5⋅lower + 0.5⋅upper - y                                     
⎪─────────────────────────               otherwise             
⎩        lower - y
```

Comment: Perfect, using the formula in `Out[53]` works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

btw, I hand-derived a python function for the plain fast sigmoid:

```
from math import copysign

def inverse_fast_sigmoid(x):
    assert -1.0 < x < 1.0
    return copysign(
        1 / (
            1 - abs(x)
        ) - 1, 
        x
    )
```

Maybe you can adjust it for your version.

Comment: It seemed tricky to solve by term-rewriting btw. I had to solve it intuitively, by reasoning about what the numbers are doing. If you write out the terms of the sigmoid function as a table and consider that it is always of the form x/x+1, i.e. 2/3, 3/4, 4/5 etc, the derivation becomes fairly obvious. trouble is you only get one side of it. Copysign to the rescue. copysign really is a useful function.